# Can't make redirect in WordPress

Tags: redirect

I'm trying to make a login form. But it doesn't redirect. 
It shows

> "Login success"; but it doesn't redirect. I also tried with:

```
wp_redirect('myurl');
```

Which is correct way to redirect in WordPress?

My code is:

```
global $wpdb;
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$query = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_login = '$username' AND user_pass='$password'");
        if ( $query != null ) {
            echo "Login success";
header("Location:myurl");

        } else {
            echo "incorrect pass or user";

            return false;
        }


<form action="" method="post"/>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/> 
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"/><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I also tried with this wp_signon:

```
function custom_login() {
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] =$username ;
    $creds['user_pass'] = $password;
```

`$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );`

if ($user)

wp_redirect('myurl');

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );

Comment: Where did you get the code from?

Comment: I've written it. Is there something that I can use? I also tried with wp_signon but it doesn't work, too.

Comment: Good to see you're having a go. Yes, please see my answer below and mark as accepted and up vote if you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <?php  wp_login_form( array(
        'echo'           => true,
        'redirect' => ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
        'form_id'        => 'loginform',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
        'id_username'    => 'user_login',
        'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
        'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
        'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
        'remember'       => true,
        'value_username' => '',
        'value_remember' => false
)); ?>
```

**2nd Parameter**

**redirect**
URL to redirect to. Must be absolute (as in, http://example.com/mypage/).

Recommended: site_url( '/mypage/ ' ).

Default: the current page

Note: You will need to configure the 2nd parameter yourself.

Comment: Could I use only this function? I also tried with this but it's not working :  function custom_login() {
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] =$username ;
    $creds['user_pass'] = $password;
    
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

  if ($user)

wp_redirect('mysiteurl');

   }   
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );

Comment: Did you try my solution? Where did you put the code?

Comment: I've download insert php plugin and I write it in my page. I'll try it now. I should write only this code?

Comment: I used your code. I logged in but in admin panel. It didn't redirect me. I want user to be redirected to another page - e.g. yotube. I tried with:  'redirect' => ( 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vB4gpXVtIs' ) , but didn't redirect.

Comment: Yes. Just replace the code in your question with the code in the answer.

Comment: I'm tring to edit page and it shows me: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Comment: If you want to redirect to the YouTube URL you would need to enter the URL like this: `'redirect' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vB4gpXVtIs';` But I'm not sure why you'd want to.

Comment: I tried with this:   'redirect' => ( 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vB4gpXVtIs' ) , but it didn't redirect. How does it work encrypting in wordpress? How does it hash passwords? Because now I haven't make register form. I login with @admin username and password, but it doesn't redirect me. I have to make a register form. How to mahe hash password?

Comment: Now I only want to redirect to a page. I haven't make this page yet. That's why I redirect to an example page like youtube. I only want to see it's working. :)

Comment: Is this code only for admin login? Because when I use it for another user it shows me: You don't have sufficient rights to access this page. I want to use it as login form for all users that will register in my site.